# Filtrar uma array e acessar o response.body de uma array multidimensional

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estou tentando avançar num projeto em angular mas to encalhado a duas semanas já.
Como eu consigo acessar uma array multidimensional com os mesmos nomes de atributo?

Inicialmente o meu json-server puxa 3 objetos com nested arrays - e dentro delas tem os mesmos nomes de atributos que as outras.

Tenho 3 na requisição inicial no console, são elas:

```
{
0: Object { name: "lotes - Listar lotes", request: {…}, response: (2) […] }
​
1: Object { name: "lotes/{id} - Buscar lote", request: {…}, response: (1) […] }
​
2: Object { name: "lotes/{id}/registros - Listar registros lote", request: {…}, response: (1) […] }
```

a parte que eu preciso é essa:

```
{
            "name": "lotes - Listar lotes",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Authorization",
                        "value": "Basic dGl2ZWE6UzRjTDdmUDl0RW1nYkNnTmxJRnBsekpBSlV5UGpVQjZkcUVKV2tnNDVYMGkw"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://{{HOST}}/api/assessorias/lotes",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "{{HOST}}"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "assessorias",
                        "lotes"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "sort",
                            "value": "situacao",
                            "description": "Ordenação",
                            "disabled": true
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "0",
                            "description": "Página (0, 1, 2...)",
                            "disabled": true
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "size",
                            "value": "50",
                            "description": "Tamanho da página",
                            "disabled": true
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "situacao",
                            "value": "ATIVO",
                            "description": "Situação - [ATIVO, INATIVO, REMOVIDO]",
                            "disabled": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": [
                {
                    "name": "lotes - *",
                    "originalRequest": {
                        "method": "GET",
                        "header": [
                            {
                                "key": "Authorization",
                                "value": "Basic dGl2ZWE6UzRjTDdmUDl0RW1nYkNnTmxJRnBsekpBSlV5UGpVQjZkcUVKV2tnNDVYMGkw"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "Content-Type",
                                "name": "Content-Type",
                                "value": "application/json",
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        ],
                        "url": {
                            "raw": "https://{{HOST}}/api/assessorias/lotes",
                            "protocol": "https",
                            "host": [
                                "{{HOST}}"
                            ],
                            "path": [
                                "api",
                                "assessorias",
                                "lotes"
                            ],
                            "query": [
                                {
                                    "key": "sort",
                                    "value": "situacao",
                                    "description": "Ordenação",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "page",
                                    "value": "0",
                                    "description": "Página (0, 1, 2...)",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "size",
                                    "value": "50",
                                    "description": "Tamanho da página",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "situacao",
                                    "value": "ATIVO",
                                    "description": "Situação - [ATIVO, INATIVO, REMOVIDO]",
                                    "disabled": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "status": "OK",
                    "code": 200,
                    "_postman_previewlanguage": "json",
                    "header": [
                        {
                            "key": "Date",
                            "value": "Fri, 07 May 2021 19:01:18 GMT"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Length",
                            "value": "219"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Connection",
                            "value": "keep-alive"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Encoding",
                            "value": "gzip"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Expires",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-has-next",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Cache-Control",
                            "value": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-total-count",
                            "value": "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-current-size",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-XSS-Protection",
                            "value": "1; mode=block"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Pragma",
                            "value": "no-cache"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Limit-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "350"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Reset-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "1000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-Quota-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "999"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-current-page",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-Frame-Options",
                            "value": "DENY"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-has-previous",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Limit-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "349"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Reset-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "15000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
                            "value": "nosniff"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-total-pages",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-number-elements",
                            "value": "5"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "9"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Quota-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "1000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cookie": [],
                    "body": "[\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1081673531130966016\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-27\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"0\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"0\",\n        \"situacao\": \"INATIVO\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1081682225134571520\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-28\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1576\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35500\",\n        \"situacao\": \"INATIVO\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1083447097597952000\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-29\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1577\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35513\",\n        \"situacao\": \"INATIVO\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1083450368450428928\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-30\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1577\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35513\",\n        \"situacao\": \"INATIVO\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1083817674049376256\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-05-01\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1577\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35513\",\n        \"situacao\": \"ATIVO\"\n    }\n]"
                },
                {
                    "name": "lotes - Ativos",
                    "originalRequest": {
                        "method": "GET",
                        "header": [
                            {
                                "key": "Authorization",
                                "value": "Basic dGl2ZWE6UzRjTDdmUDl0RW1nYkNnTmxJRnBsekpBSlV5UGpVQjZkcUVKV2tnNDVYMGkw"
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "Content-Type",
                                "name": "Content-Type",
                                "value": "application/json",
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        ],
                        "url": {
                            "raw": "https://{{HOST}}/api/assessorias/lotes?situacao=ATIVO",
                            "protocol": "https",
                            "host": [
                                "{{HOST}}"
                            ],
                            "path": [
                                "api",
                                "assessorias",
                                "lotes"
                            ],
                            "query": [
                                {
                                    "key": "sort",
                                    "value": "situacao",
                                    "description": "Ordenação",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "page",
                                    "value": "0",
                                    "description": "Página (0, 1, 2...)",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "size",
                                    "value": "50",
                                    "description": "Tamanho da página",
                                    "disabled": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "situacao",
                                    "value": "ATIVO",
                                    "description": "Situação - [ATIVO, INATIVO, REMOVIDO]"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "status": "OK",
                    "code": 200,
                    "_postman_previewlanguage": "json",
                    "header": [
                        {
                            "key": "Date",
                            "value": "Wed, 28 Apr 2021 22:22:09 GMT"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "application/json"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Length",
                            "value": "134"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Connection",
                            "value": "keep-alive"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Content-Encoding",
                            "value": "gzip"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Expires",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-has-next",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Cache-Control",
                            "value": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-total-count",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-current-size",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-XSS-Protection",
                            "value": "1; mode=block"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "Pragma",
                            "value": "no-cache"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Limit-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "350"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Reset-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "1000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-Quota-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "1000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-current-page",
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-Frame-Options",
                            "value": "DENY"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-has-previous",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Limit-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-hmlassessoria",
                            "value": "349"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Reset-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "15000"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
                            "value": "nosniff"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-total-pages",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "x-meta-number-elements",
                            "value": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Remaining-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "9"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "X-RateLimit-Quota-hmlassessoria_assessoria.a",
                            "value": "1000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cookie": [],
                    "body": "[\n    {\n        \"id\": \"1081682225134571520\",\n        \"dataProcessamento\": \"2021-04-28\",\n        \"quantidadeClientes\": \"1576\",\n        \"quantidadeParcelas\": \"35500\",\n        \"situacao\": \"ATIVO\"\n    }\n]"
                }
            ]
```

a o serviço da request é esse:

```
  readonly apiURL = `http://localhost:3000`;
  readonly lotesURL = 'item';

        getLotes(situacao: situacao.ATIVO){
        let params = new HttpParams()
        .set('situacao', situacao);
        return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(`${this.apiURL}/${this.lotesURL}/`,{params: params})
    }
```

esse é meu componente:

```
import { Lote, response, situacao} from 'src/app/services/lotes.service';
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
import { HeaderService } from 'src/app/services/header-service.service';
import { LotesService } from 'src/app/services/lotes.service';
import { PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-lotes',
  templateUrl: './lotes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lotes.component.css'],
})

//status 200 sempre
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LotesComponent implements OnInit {
  //onde irá ser gerada a array dos lotes e
  //configuração das colunas da tabela que irá ser mostrada
  MostrarColunas: string[] = ['id', 'dataProcessamento', 'quantidadeClientes', "quantidadeParcelas", "situacao"];
  lotes: Lote[] = [];
  dataSource = this.lotes;
  response : response[] = [];
  pageslice = this.lotes.slice(0, 5);

  //paginação
  pageSize = 3;
  pageIndex = 0;
  pageSizeOptions = [3, 6, 9];
  showFirstLastButtons = true;
  handlePageEvent(event: PageEvent) {
    const startIndex = event.pageIndex * event.pageSize;
    let endIndex = startIndex + event.pageSize;
    if (endIndex > this.lotes.length) {
      endIndex = this.lotes.length;
    }
    this.pageslice = this.lotes.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
  }

  constructor(private loteService: LotesService,
    private headerService: HeaderService,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      this.lotes = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headerService.setTitle('Lotes');
    this.BuscaLotes();
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
  
  BuscaLotes() {
    this.loteService.getLotes(situacao.ATIVO).subscribe(
      (response:any) => {
        this.response = response;
        this.lotes = response;
        console.log(this.lotes);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

minha dúvida é:
eu preciso achar uma forma de acessar o response.body do primeiro apenas(Lotes - Listar Lotes), mas na requisição ele puxa esses 3..
Já tentei usar **pluck do rxjs, filtrar por index, query strings, map, filter**, mas nenhum me atendeu corretamente, ou provavelmente não usei da forma correta

obs: é uma API de terceiros então a rigor eu não tenho acesso a ela pra fazer modificações.. esse é o padrão de projeto deles

Comment: Não ficou clara sua dúvida, ficaria melhor se postasse o array completo!

Comment: postei! o json é meio grande e passou do limite de caracteres, mas basicamente é a parte que eu preciso acessar.. é um json bem complexo, no caso preciso acessar o body dos lotes ativos

Comment: Cara tá bem confuso esse retorno, mas, pelo que postou terá que pegar a variável que guardou o retorno e aí acessar a propriedade **response** tipo `this.data.response` percorrer pq é um array com um map, forEach ou for que é melhor. Fazer um **`if`** pra ver se a propriedade **name** é igual a `"lotes - Ativos"` e se for igual acessar a propriedade **body** que tbm é um array ou seja terá que percorre-lo tbm. Isso pelo json que postou!

Comment: é foi o que pensei.. isso eu acho que já me ajuda bastante.. eu tinha uma idéia de como fazer mas não sabia exatamente... sou bem novato em angular e typescript então to fazendo tudo meio no susto.. vou tentar aqui e se conseguir atualizo o tópico com a resolução, obrigado!